# Showing full post instead of excerpt with Bueno theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I was wondering if someone here could help me with [my site](http://www.metalgearinformer.com), which uses the Bueno theme (Wordpress CMS). I tried asking in the theme's support forum, but I didn't get any response.

The main issue I have is that the theme automatically displays excerpts on the front page instead of the full post. The situation I would like is to have it show the entire post, unless I use the 'more' tag in the editor. But at the moment it breaks posts off on its own and ignores the more tag.

I've tried looking for a solution myself, but the code of the theme doesn't seem to have `<*?php the_excerpt(); ?>` that I can change to `<*?php the_content(); ?>`, which is the suggestion I see everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be this: Under *Theme Options -> General Settings* set the Post Content to Full Content.

Or, if not, open `index.php` and change

```
<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == "content" ) {
the_content('[...]'); } else { the_excerpt(); ?><?php } ?>

to

<?php the_content('[...]'); ?>
```

See http://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201460727-Excerpt-Full-Post-Problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, that solution seems to be for an older version of Bueno. The problem started when a completely new version of the theme was released (before that, the excerpts worked properly).